# Bike type suggestion for packed limestone trails

Tags: mountain-bike

Where I live (Ontario, Canada), I am lucky enough to have access to a number of packed limestone trails (former railways). These are fairly flat and great for bicycling. They are mixed use, so sometimes they are very uneven - mostly from dried up horse tracks or farming machinery.

I am currently using a cheap supermarket bike; the ride is really bumpy and uncomfortable at times. I was thinking of upgrading to a proper mountain bike, but I am wondering if that would be overkill as the trails are pretty flat. Should I go with a bike with front suspension only, or both front and back? Any suggestions are appreciated.

I also have a hybrid bike (Specialized Sirius Sport) but the thin tires and clip-in pedals make it less than ideal for those trails and I feel like I am damaging it.

Comment: Knobby, fat tires (2.0 and up) should do with any bike, even without front suspension.

Comment: They have "packed limestone" in Wisconsin and the trails are easily smooth enough for road bikes.  It really depends on the specific trail

Comment: I ride the exact same bike, a Specialized Sirius Sport, on packed limestone daily without trouble to me or the machine.

Comment: @kmm, thanks, I may give it a shot. I may just put back on old pedals - I do not know if I am physically challenged, but when riding with other people, I often find myself in situations, where they just do not click out when needed.

Comment: Some pictures of the trail would help.  I've ridden packed/crushed limestone trails for years on tires from 23mm slicks to 2.1" MTB with suspension and frankly it was always fine except for the odd trail made more of big chunky bits which is only really good for walking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to a full suspesion - waste of good money on these trails, you need $2K to get one thats half decent - however if you have got $2.5K burning a hole in you pocket, full sus will be more comfortable.  A Hardtail MTB is built a little heavier than a hybrid, but in the end, I doubt very much it would make a difference.

What I would do is look at some cheap upgrades to your existing bike. Go to the biggest tires you can fit (Without going insane) 2" would be good - rim width and frame cleance need to be considered. No only comfort, you might want to consider a shock seat post. These are a often considered "poor mans softtail", but do not get the attention they deserve - they do take some of teh stress and shock loading off the frame and wheels. They are great for taking the small ( <25mm ) bumps on these kinds of trail while remaining seated.

If you decide to go for a new bike, a quailty steel hardtail MTB or hybrid would be my pick (unless you can afford carbon or titanium), with low travel shocks (80mm, no more than 100). A 29er (29" / 700C wheels) rolls better over the rough than 26" and are ideal for these kinds of trails

Comment: He might also look at a shock absorbing stem (The [Girvin Flexstem](http://www.bikepro.com/products/stems/girvin.html)  is one example) as well as thick foam handgrips to reduce vibrations in the handlebar. When I ride on rough roads, it's my hands that suffer more than my butt.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful. You guys gave me something to think about. Yeah, handlebar vibrations get to me too.

Comment: @SebastianK Handlebar vibrations can be reduced using new bartape and an extra layer, or fit some grips that are thicker than the traditional hard plastic ones.  You can also wear padded biking gloves, or if its cold plain old winter gloves work well.     Also, try not locking your elbows; keep them slightly bent for shock absorbtion.  Check your tyre/tire pressures, drop them by 5 PSI and see if it helps.  Lastly, shorten the stem or raise the bars to decrease the weight you're putting on your hands.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with upgrading the Hybrid you have,or get a 29er and use slightly less knobbly tyres, Schwalbe "Big Apples" are a great tyre for that sort of riding and they can be a good suspension, or at least lower the rumbling in your wrists.

Comment: Gidday and welcome to SE Bicycles.  Thank you for your contribution.